# Declaration for Array of pointers in Virtual Dispatch

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers, virtual-functions

Let's say we have three functions as below:

```
int fun1()
{
    cout<<"inside fun1"<<endl;
}

int fun2()
{
    cout<<"inside fun2"<<endl;
}

int fun3(int i)
{
    cout<<"inside fun3"<<endl;
}
```

Then I can declare array of pointers to function for accessing the first two functions like below:

```
int (*p[2])() = {fun1, fun2};

for (int i=0;i<2;++i)
{
    p[i]();
}
```

I am curious on the declaration and access mechanism when above functions are declared virtual inside a Base Class B. Can someone please explain to me how the function pointers  are stored inside the array of pointer and how are they called using the array of pointers.

Comment: Have you tried say a google search? Like [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+virtual+functions+in+C%2B%2B+work)? Do you find information returned by such a search lacking? In what ways?

Comment: @ n.m. , Thanks for your response. I am not able to comprehend the syntax on how to declare the array of pointers as the third function takes int parameter whereas first two takes no parameters.

Comment: @CppLearner: you can't put that third function in the same array as the other ones in C++, they don't have the same type. That doesn't mean the _compiler_ can't produce code that does something similar. The vtable (if that's what your compiler uses) is outside the language.

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in [pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html)? It doesn't matter whether they are virtual or not.

Comment: @Mat, Thanks. So does that mean there is no way we can simulate the behavior of array of pointers to different function types. n.m.- I am interested in simulating this behavior.

Comment: @n.m. - Actually I want to declare an array of pointers pointing to different types of  function signatures

Comment: You cannot. All array elements have the same type.

Comment: If you are using virtual functions, you should NEVER need to use function pointers - if you are, it's a "bad smell" - bad smell is a term used for "code that is doing the wrong thing" (just like if your food in the fridge smells bad, code that smells bad should not be used!)

Comment: @Mats Petersson: I am not using it. I read that vtables are generally implemented via Array of function pointers. I am just trying to simulate/understand that behavior.

Comment: You can simulate this behaviour by using a struct of different function pointers, rather than an array of function pointers.

Comment: So, the compiler knows what functions are being held at what index in the vtable. It is not, really, an array, more, as n.m. says, a struct.

Comment: Thanks all for your patience and taking time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that pointers to functions and pointers to member functions are *entirely* different beasts and there is no way to convert between them. That is, you won't be able to store a pointer to any member function whether `virtual` or not into an `int(*)()`, or more general, an `R(*)(Args...)`. Pointer to functions just store the address of the function to be called.

Member functions require a pointer to an object to be passed to them. If you want to store a pointer to a member function you'll need something declared like `int (B::*)()` (or more general `R(C::*)(Args...)`), e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    virtual ~B() {}
    void         non_virtual_fn()      { std::cout << "B::non_virtual_fn\n"; }
    virtual void virtual_fn()          { std::cout << "B::virtual_fn\n"; }
};

struct D: B {
    void         non_virtual_fn()      { std::cout << "D::non_virtual_fn\n"; }
    void         virtual_fn() override { std::cout << "D::virtual_fn\n"; }
};

void (B::*members[])() = {
    &B::non_virtual_fn,
    &B::virtual_fn,
};

template <typename T, int Size>
int size(T (&)[Size]) {
    return Size;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    D d;
    for (int i(0); i != size(members); ++i) {
        (b.*members[i])();
        (d.*members[i])();
    }
}
```

What the compiler actually stores for the member pointers isn't specified. Most likely it stores a pointer to the member function for non-`virtual` member functions and a [*thunk*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) for `virtual` functions.

If you want to call member and non-member functions based on what's stored in your array, you'll need to type erase some of the details, e.g., using `std::function<Signature>`. To call a member function you'll still need to provide an object to the call, of course, which you can do using `std::bind()` or a suitable lambda function.

Comment: Big +1 for `std::bind`.

Comment: Thanks Dietmar Kühl for detailed explanation. I still have a doubt, what if there is a third function "virtual void virtual_fn1(int value)". How it will be stored in B::*members[]. Could you please add some info.

Comment: @CppLearner: since the signature is different, it won't be able to store a pointer to member function to `B::virtual_fn1(int)` into an array of `void (B::*)()`. You'd need an array of `void (B::*)(int)` for this purpose.